PuTTY copy and paste container within SSH
I use PuTTY all the time to SSH into a server.  Within that server, I then connect into a container.  Within the server, I can use the standard PuTTY copy/paste using highlight and right click to copy and paste.  Everything works fine.  But when I then exec into the container I can no longer copy/paste.  Any ideas of what I need to do/change?

Open Server 1 using PuTTY

Copy and paste works as expected


from the prompt on that server docker exec -it <container> bash

Copy and paste no longer works



Any idea what I can do to make PuTTY cut and paste within this container?

That's...just weird.  How are you trying to cut and paste?  What if you use C and V, respectively?  How is it failing if you right-click the mouse for copy and paste?  Do you get an error?  Did you try copying from withing PuTTY, and pasting into eg. Notepad?  What about copying from eg. Notepad, and pasting into PutTTY?  Come to think of it, what are the current PuTTY settings for copy and paste?

Maybe there is some utility that requests PuTTY to report terminal mouse events to the remote host, and the transition into the container fails to reset that? Or incorrect terminal type settings within the container cause a wrong terminal control code to be sent to PuTTY that makes it report mouse events to the remote side instead of performing a local copy/paste?
Anyway, try holding Shift while highlighting/pasting to override any remote mouse event reporting functions and use PuTTY's usual copy/paste.
